# Is the お used at the start of the sentence a honorific お?

Tags: honorifics

Is the お used at the start of the following dialogue a honorific お?

> [お得意の洗脳か]

[image: Page 16 Phantom Ein Novella]

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but in this case it is sarcastic by being too polite.

Comment: *reads your comment, pauses, thinks about the character saying it, bursts into giggling while nodding my head enthusiastically* Ha ha, yes, I can actually see her doing that... Now, ha ha, do you have any tips as to how I can show over-polite sarcasm in English?